# How to sort jagged array from an array?

Tags: c#

```
var jaggedarray = new int[3][];

jaggedarray[0] = new int[5] { 99, 999, 49, 79, 59 };
jaggedarray[1] = new int[3] { 199, 1999, 149 };
jaggedarray[2] = new int[2] { 999, 500 };
```

- from this jagged array, I want it to be sorting the rows against by a different array1D (can be *integer or string*),
- of course the number of rows in the jagged array is equal to the number of elements in array1D, for example:

Example

```
object[] array1D= {12,7,3}
```

**Edit:**
The number of elements and data types in the jagged array is random, what I need to look for is the new positions after sorting from array1D, and based on these new positions to sort for the jagged array.

based on the results ordered from array1D, after sorting, my desired result for jagged array is:

```
jaggedarray[0] =new int[2] { 999, 500 };  
jaggedarray[1] = new int[3] { 199, 1999, 149 };
jaggedarray[2] = new int[5] { 99, 999, 49, 79, 59 };
```

I have been looking for articles about jagged arrays but most of them mention its column sorting.

How can i sort a jagged array from other array?

Comment: "*I want it to be sorting the rows against by a different array1*" - explain this.. how does this `{12,7,3}` sort your arrays?

Comment: Hi @MichaelRandall, after sorting, the result from array 1D is {3,7,12}, I'll sort jagged array rows based on the new element positions in array1D.

Comment: @NguyenManh You can use method [Array.Sort()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_) to solve your problem: `Array.Sort(array1D, jaggedarray);`. It will sort `jaggedArray` based on the values of the `array1D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you could [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1) your 2 array sets together, then use [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1) on the elements in the 1D array, `Select` (*project*) out the original array, then use `ToArray` to  back to your jagged array

```
object[] array1D = {12, 7, 3};

var results = jaggedarray
   .Zip(array1D, (ints, objects) => (ints, objects))
   .OrderBy(x => x.objects)
   .Select(x => x.ints)
   .ToArray();
    
foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

**Output**

```
999, 500
199, 1999, 149
99, 999, 49, 79, 59
```

Update, or embarrassingly (for me), use `Array.Sort()` :)

Comment: wouldn't the answer be better if you removed everything but the `Array.Sort()` suggestion? you don't need to stay true to history and note updates ;)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/316262

Comment: @Neuron of course..